# How to use Microsoft Graph in C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm getting the error

> Unable to retrieve user's mysite URL

when I do any query to OneDrive. My complete code below and I'm just running it on Windows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

namespace MSGraphTests
{
    class Program
    {
        static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientId)
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .WithAuthority(new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/v2.0"))
                .Build();

            // Retrieve an access token for Microsoft Graph (gets a fresh token if needed).
            var authResult = await confidentialClient
                    .AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                    .ExecuteAsync();

            var token = authResult.AccessToken;
            Console.WriteLine(token);

            // Build the Microsoft Graph client. As the authentication provider, set an async lambda
            // which uses the MSAL client to obtain an app-only access token to Microsoft Graph,
            // and inserts this access token in the Authorization header of each API request. 
            GraphServiceClient graphClient =
                new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
                {
                    // Add the access token in the Authorization header of the API request.
                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                })
            );
          
            var children = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Root.Children
               .Request()
               .GetAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine in Graph Explorer and I have the `Files.ReadWrite.All` and `User.Read.All` permissions set both for Delegate and Application in Azure. I do get the token in the line `Console.WriteLine(token)`.

I'm sure this is just an issue with my code and not permissions as I'm able to send queries using the O365 python library. How can I get this working?

Comment: Could you please check your token has the required permission [here](https://jwt.io/), additionally, are you using `Microsoft graph SDK`?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Yes its microsoft graph. I just checked the token and it has the roles `Files.ReadWrite.All` and `User.Read.All`. In Azure these have been set both as Delegate and Application permissions

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Oh I've just checked the token for graph explorer and it has a line `scp` listing all the scopes. This `scp` is not there in the token I receive in my program.

Comment: No you should have this fiedls `"roles": [
    "Files.ReadWrite.All",
    "Sites.ReadWrite.All"
  ]` and `admin grand consent`

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Thanks. I did try various configurations including `Sites.readWrite.All` and esured admin consent is granted but with no luck.

Comment: I found the solution. i realised i have to set the scopes under 'Expose an API' in Azure. i was initially adding permissions in the API permissions page. Its really shocking how much documentation there is all over the place takes a while to really find anything, a bit of luck sometimes

Comment: So may I post this misconfiguration setup as answer, that on `Expose an API` that you have got know from checking in ` "roles": [     "Files.ReadWrite.All",     "Sites.ReadWrite.All"   ]` files  extracting the token into [https://jwt.io/](https://jwt.io/)